# Куда поместить создание объекта адаптера: во фрагмент со списком (ListView) или в активити с фрагментом?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Имеется одна Activity и один фрагмент, содержащий компонент listView. Разметка Activity включает фрагмент со списковым элементом. Есть Адаптер для списка. Где создавать объект этого адаптера: в классе фрагмента или в классе Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть `фрагмент` и `активити`, то конечно же во фрагменте, т.к. в нем создается `ListView`.
В приложении получается такая иерархия (сверху вниз) `активити` - `фрагмент` -`ListView`. `Adapter` связан с `ListView` и выносить его на самый высокий уровень не логично.

Разделяйте функционал ваших классов. Пусть `активити` управляет только фрагментом, и она ничего не должна знать о `ListView`, `фрагмент` управляет `ListView` и вот на этом этапе надо создавать `Adapter`.

Возникает вопрос, чем конкретно занимается фрагмент: отображает только определенный список (список котиков например) или `ListView` в фрагменте может быть разным, в зависимости от того что творится в активити.

В первом случае `Adapter` определенно должен быть в фрагменте, т.к. от `активити` ничего не зависит.

Во втором случае `активити` должна фрагменту передавать какой-то параметр, от которого зависит `ListView`, но опять таки `Adapter` в этом случае можно создавать во фрагменте в зависимости от параметра.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас встал такой вопрос, то в данном случае фрагмент Вам не нужен. Одна из фишек фрагментов - это возможность использования фрагмента в разных активити, а если адаптер будет жить отдельно от фрагмента с ListView - то грош цена такому фрагменту ;)